# Appending <head> with jQuery - doesn't seem to work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting to create a main js controller that includes all needed js files for my application to keep everything as structured as possible.

I thought this would work, but it doesn't seem to append anything to `head`:

**HTML:**

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../static/css/sub/navbar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../static/js/includes.js"></script>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>
```

*As you can see `includes.js` is imported after jQuery from Google's CDN*

**Contents of includes.js:**

```
var scripts = ['../static/js/functions/notifications.js', '../static/js/functions/subnavbar.js'];
$(document).ready( function() {
    var iterate = scripts.length;
    for(i = 0; i < iterate; i++) {
        $('head').append('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + scripts[i] + '"></script>');
    }
});
```

I have no idea why it's not appending the contents of the array `scripts` to `head`. I tested out the script by appending the contents to `body` ([see this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rjMyB/)).

Any answers as to why it's not working, or edits to make it work would be greatly appreciated :)!

Comment: The JSFiddle isn't appending scripts, you've thrown away the script element parts.

Comment: How do you know it isn't working? What have you done to test it?

Comment: Since the files won't exist on JSFiddle, it isn't a very good place to build a test case for this (unless you switch in absolute URIs).

Comment: I've tested that the javascript above actually prints `<script..>` and that something isn't going wrong on that end. I've attempted to use the example below, and got a different result to the author (comment is on the answer below).

Comment: **How** did you test that it prints `<script..>`?

Comment: You're right, I didn't actually, I'll retract that. I tested that it iterated over and printed the array values fine, but not encased within `<script>`. I went two steps ahead, thought it would have worked without realizing that `<script..>` won't print as plain text in the body. My bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to consider: this problem has been solved for you already, and an awesome JavaScript library already exists.  It's called **[Require JS](http://requirejs.org/)**.

I strongly recommend checking it out to see if it'll work for your requirements before rolling your own dependency loader.

Answer (score 0):

You are using jQuery, why not using $.getScript?
This works fine in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/x6rCr/